# In python, even though I imported no modules, how I'm able to use functions like sort, append, insert, etc?

Tags: python, module

I have just started learning Python. I was just testing different features of python on python's console in Terminal (Ubuntu's terminal).

Even though I didn't imported any modules, how can I could still use functions like append(), insert(), print(), etc.

I used to program in C language, where I must include 'stdio.h' header file just to 'print' a string. So I was expecting same behaviour in Python.

Is there any standard Module which is by default imported in every Python program's 'interpretation'?

Comment: Some of these (like `list.append()`) are methods that come with the built-in objects. Others, like `print()`, are [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Comment: Python is not C, and you should stop assuming it works anything like C. It's a very different language.

Comment: To be exact, you don't have to include any header files in C  if you pass the command line option `-Wno-implicit-function-declaration` (*you shouldn't do it, but it's possible*).

Answer (score 1):

You could check the modules that are loaded in a python file by running

```
import sys
sys.module.keys()
```

Functions like print are part of the `__builtin__` module that is loaded by default.

Comment: I got this message when I tried it:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'module'**

Comment: and, I'm trying Python directly by calling python3 program in Terminal (command prompt equivalent of Windows, I think) of Ubuntu. I'm not using any text editor to write a .py file and execute it.

Comment: @ByteManager it's supposed to be `sys.modules`, but really, the built-in namespace has a special status, it isn't just another module. It is actually a "true global" scope that should generally not be touched. In any case, all you should know is that Python has several built-in types and functions.